# "AttributeError: 'str' has no attribute" when trying to assign additional attributes to variable

Tags: python

I am getting this error when running this code in Python 3:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "runing"
        self.display = "window1"
        self.display.window = "None"
        self.display.window.width = 1920
        self.display.window.height = 1080
        self.display.window.name = "Space Shooter Game"
        self.display.fps = 30

game = Game()
```

Error message:

```
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    game = Game()
  File "test.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.display.window = "None"
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'window'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think that the error message explicitly tells you everything. display attribute is assigned a String value, which does not have the attribute window.

Comment: You could make another class called `Display` to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Multi layer variable are not available in python : `self.display.window = "None"` do instead `self.display_window = "None"`

Comment: Which other language has multi layer variables?

Comment: No, I was curious from which language you know this feature that is missing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can be used for muli-layer attributes

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "runing"
        self.display = dict()
        self.display["window"] = dict()
        self.display["window"]["width"] = 1920
        self.display["window"]["height"] = 1080
        self.display["window"]["name"] = "Space Shooter Game"
        self.display["fps"] = 30


game = Game()
```